# How to convert z coordinate to an angle in c#?

Tags: c#, vector, angle, degrees

---

I've been searching the net for hours to convert z-axis coordinate to an angle. I've already got x,y to angle and now to complete it i need the z. Here is the code for x,y:

```
        private float XYToDegrees(Point xy, Point origin)
    {
        int deltaX = origin.X - xy.X;
        int deltaY = origin.Y - xy.Y;

        double radAngle = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        double degreeAngle = radAngle * 180.0 / Math.PI;

        return (float)(180.0 - degreeAngle);
    }
```

and this code to run the function:

```
XYToDegrees(new Point(2334, -447), new Point(2433, -659)) - 270;
```

---

The purpose of the z coordinate to angle is to get the camera angle aligned with
the object I'm looking at.

Comment: do you know the mathematical function to convert z into coordinates other than cartesian? Do you know if you want to go to polar or cylindrical?

Comment: Most 3d engines and environments have a `camera.LookAt(obj)` functionality. If yours done have one, you can look up an algorithm for the `LookAt` method and implement it. Don't re-invent the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simmilar, just another triangle

```
private float XYZToDegrees(double deltaX, double deltaY, double deltaZ)
{
    double deltaXY = Math.Sqrt(deltaY * deltaY + deltaX * deltaX);
    double radAngle = Math.Atan2(deltaZ, deltaXY);
    double degreeAngle = radAngle * 180.0 / Math.PI;

    return (float)degreeAngle;
}
```

Comment: Great solution!